# Canadian married to an American (10 years) considering relocating to the USA

Tags: usa

My husband and I married in Canada in Oct 2009 he is American born I am am Canadian born. Almost 2 years later he was finally able to relocate to Canada and we've been living here, together for 8 years. We are considering relocating to the US to be near his family.

We are looking at selling our home (primary residence) here do we have to pay disposition tax on our home? What do the percentages look like? Do you pay disposition tax to move your belongings to the USA like furniture, household items?

I work remotely for a Canadian company from my home office and do site visits on occassion. If I can convince my employer to keep me on, working remotely from the USA how does that look? What is required? How long before I can get a green card? Do I need one? Do I then have to pay taxes in two counties?  Any advice before we just leap head first?

Comment: The tax questions might get a better or quicker answer at [Money.SE].  I would split this question into three: one concerning the disposition tax, one concerning the green card, and one concerning remote work by a US resident for a Canadian employer.

Comment: On the green card front, a first step you can do today is to talk to a US immigration lawyer. The simplest way is to apply for a US immigrant visa first, and stay in Canada until you get it. The current [I-130 processing time](https://egov.uscis.gov/processing-times/) for this is something like 9 months.

Comment: I would add to @krubo's comment that if you take that route, your immigrant visa will serve as a temporary green card after you enter the US, until you receive the actual card in the mail some weeks later, so you will not be stuck in the US waiting for the card.  If you try to [adjust status](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjustment_of_status) while you are in the US, you will be stuck in the US for some time after you file the application and before either you receive your [advance parole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advance_parole) or the application is approved.

Comment: You didn't mention whether your husband has gotten Canadian citizenship, but if not, then that's another thing to consider: In case you might ever return to live in Canada, it might be a good idea for him to naturalize as a dual citizen before you move.